# Python loop using the index number as part of a key name

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python - getting my feet wet.

I want to create a loop that looks for ip addresses and uses the loop count as part of a key name.

i.e.

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
  ip1= re.search(r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}', commandslist)
  if ip1:
    myip1 = ip1.group()
    commandslist = commandslist.replace(myip1,'')
    print 'found', ip1.group()
   i=i+1
```

what I'd like to do is where it says ip1 or myip1 replace the 1 with the current value of i.  I've tried ip[i] and that just tosses errors about not being defined.  defining ip=range(0,5) doesn't seem to help at all.

Can anyone point me back to the correct path?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't understand the point of the loop. You're checking the same regex against the same string each time, so why are you looping?

Comment: @Daniel It's not the same string, `commandslist` is modified in each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No loop is necessary, you can simply write:

```
myip = re.findall(r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}', commandslist)
```

---

When you really need loops, avoid this:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    # do something with i
    i = i + 1
```

and use this instead:

```
for i in xrange(5):
    # do something with i
```

When you need to iterate over elements of a list, use this:

```
for e in l:
    # do something with e
```

---

In your case, a complete example might look like:

```
import re

commandslist = 'Lorem 192.168.0.1, ipsum 127.0.0.1: 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2.'
myips = re.findall(r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}', commandslist)
for ip in myips:
    print 'found ', ip
```

Comment: would you access the index in the same way?  i.e. myip[1] ?

Comment: @Chasester Yes, `findall` returns a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
ip = [None, ] * 5
myip = [None, ] * 5
```

Add this above your code. Then you use it like this: `ip[i] = ...`, `myip[i] = ...`

Comment: that did it, still trying to get used to Python's methods of doing things.  thank you!

Comment: You actually don't need the comma unless you're working with tuples instead of lists, so [None] * 5 is sufficient here.

Answer (score 0):

Python encourages the programmer to allocate space for storage when it is needed.
In your attempt, allocate empty lists for `ip` and `myip`, then use `.append` to add elements when necessary.

The lists will grow to any (reasonable) length, and the code will not depend on initial allocation size.
The `ip[-1]` notation references the last element of a sequence.
The running index `i` is not used inside the loop.

```
ip = []
myip = []
i = 0
while i < 5:
    ip.append(re.search(r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}', commandslist))
    if ip[-1]:
        myip.append(ip[-1].group())
        commandslist = commandslist.replace(myip[-1],'')
        print 'found', ip[-1].group()
    i=i+1
```

Please go over the tutorial, and pay special attention to the [`lists`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) introduction.

Comment: you know, during one of my earlier attempts at this, I banged around this solution except didnt have the -1